# Spring mvc controller getting multiple rows values

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, extjs

I have multiple input values, rows may 1, 10, 20 or 100 or more and columns may be 3 or more as shown here 
[image: requirment]

Questions:

1) In spring controller how do I get the values for each rows? I need exact values for all the corresponding values. e.g: row 1 Expense Activities values match with accounts and  corresponding description. Here Expense Activities, Accounts are drop down boxes and description is text field.

2) I have another tab called Expense which is similar to Earnings salary as shown in image. How can get the values for multiple blocks.

I am using Spring mvc with ext-js as front end technologies.

Answer (score 0):

Your questions are fairly hard to answer given the lack of detail as to what you are doing.
In similar spring-ext apps I have written I use a store backed by a rest proxy to back my ext grid.  This will give you certain client-server communications for free.  for more reading on the ext js side try:

[Ext.data.Store](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store) 
[Ext.data.proxy.Rest](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Rest)

Its not too hard to expand the [grid example](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/guide/grid) to use a rest proxy which will give you a good ground in how set your grid up for client-server communication.

Then in your spring controller you can will need to implement and annotate the methods for the CRUD operations that the ext proxy will send requests to. 
A handy guide for getting started with writing a restful web service with spring:

[Spring REST Service](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/)

In your specific case (and I'm guessing here because I'm not 100% sure what you're asking) you would need a spring controller method annotated with something like: 
`@RequestMapping(value="/expense", method=RequestMethod.GET)` 
You would back this with whatever business logic is used to load the grid and pass the data structure as most likely a JSON object.
For updates from the client you would then have another spring controller method, only this time anotated something like: 
`@RequestMapping(value="/expense", method=RequestMethod.POST)` for create or 
`@RequestMapping(value="/expense/{id}", method=RequestMethod.PUT)` for updates

Obviously if you're data structures are more complicated then the JSON objects sent over the wire will be correspndingly complex.

Hopefully this will set you on the path to getting your app working.